# Bluetooth stopped working suddenly on Dell XPS 13 9360 Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, dell, atheros

I had connected my bluetooth headphones to my laptop when laptop went to sleep due to no activity. When I turned it back on, bluetooth was not working. i.e. there was no bluetooth icon on the menu bar, bluetooth manager blueman was greyed out, and gave a pop-up error "adapter not found".

I have tried reinstalling blueman, pulseaudio, latest linux kernel, firmware etc. but none of these solutions seem to be able to get bluetooth working again.

Bluetooth does not show up in `rfkill list all`

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`sudo lshw -C network` output:

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
       logical name: wlp58s0
       version: 32
       serial: 9c:b6:d0:f1:43:cd
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.15.0-041500rc6-lowlatency firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00051-QCARMSWP-1 ip=192.168.1.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:135 memory:dc000000-dc1fffff
```

`lspci` output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5904 (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d18 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d58 (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
3a:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
3b:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
3c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba America Info Systems Device 0116
```

`uname -a` output:

```
Linux Barad-dur 4.15.0-041500rc6-lowlatency #201712312330 SMP PREEMPT Sun Dec 31 23:33:42 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`lsmod | grep bluetooth; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'` output:

```
bluetooth             544768  13 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,btusb
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
[    0.073891] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.922677] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin (v1.1)
[    3.244634] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.244888] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.244892] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.244894] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.244899] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.584150] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.584151] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.584155] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    7.352205] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
[    7.576028] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:3a:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    7.576034] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:3a:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    7.578921] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00051-QCARMSWP-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp crc32 c3fd4411
```

I would appreciate any help possible to get bluetooth working normally.

**EDIT:**

Just as it randomly stopped working, it has now randomly started working again and I have no idea why. But I guess, so long as it is working, I won't complain.

Comment: You should try to load previous kernels. Recent update will brakes bluetooth module detection, bt driver, firmware loading by kernel.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that if it happens again. It somehow started working again without me doing anything new.

Comment: Have the same issue here. It worked with my tecknet mouse  and suddenly the bluetooth adapter can't be found anymore

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this answer, [Dell XPS 13 (9370) Bluetooth issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024281/dell-xps-13-9370-bluetooth-issues)

Removing my XPS 15 9560 from Power and then closing the lid (to suspend) and then resuming after a few minutes seemed to be the best way to bring back Bluetooth.

Comment: I'm shocked but this actually worked for my Dell XPS 13 9343 as well.

Comment: works for XPS 13 9360 as well, don't even have to wait for a few minutes - just make sure it's really suspended