# Bluetooth on XPS13 9370 with Ubuntu 18.04 disappears

Tags: drivers, 18.04, bluetooth, dell, xps

Every time I leave the `XPS13` for about 30-60 minutes, the `Bluetooth` symbol disappears and the mouse stops working.

I have already tried to install this drivers: https://www.killernetworking.com/driver-downloads/kb/faq/1-killer-1535-1525-1435-in-ubuntu-debian

Also installed this one: https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverId=1JVK3
where I have overwritten these files:

```
AthrBT_0x00000302.dfu (size 40876) -> rampatch_usb_00000302.bin (size 32940)
ramps_0x00000302_48.dfu (size 1982) -> nvm_usb_00000302.bin (size 1953)
```

Also tried to restart bluetooth: `sudo service bluetooth restart`

But its not working until computer restart! Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Might be USB autosuspend, see https://hamwaves.com/usb.autosuspend/en/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the solution was to install the new `Kernel`, even tough I have updated to 18.04., the Kernel was still `4.15.0.30.32`, so I updated to `4.17.13` and now everything works fine.

Unfortunately I don't know whether the solution was on to install the new Kernel or a combination of using the driver mentioned above and a few other things I have tried meanwhile.

Comment: In order to install the newer kernel, rather than selecting a specific one and missing out on bug and security fixes, it's best to install the parent package: `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04`.  At the time of writing this pulled in 4.18.0.20.70.

Comment: Using kernel 4.18.0-20-generic #21~18.04.1-Ubuntu didn't resolve the issues on my 9370 :(

Comment: May try version `5.1.x`. Also works fine for me...

Comment: how did you install 5.1.x?  The [linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge) packge is only 5.0, and I don't see any official 5.1 packages in the [kernel section](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/kernel/)

Comment: You can use Ukuu for easy install https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem, lots of info at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029474/ubuntu-18-04-dell-xps13-9370-no-longer-suspends-on-lid-close). AT least your XPS appears to sleep...mine doesn't, it just suspends, hoping both will get fixed!Edit:you will need to read the comments...

Comment: That said, restarting bluetooth using the very same command as you mention works for me when mine gets disabled, in fact I have it in an easy-to-type-name script.

Comment: Unfortunately your link contains no useful info in terms of bluetooth

Comment: It does if you look closely enough in the comments like I said! Look for for a heading of "Permanent Fix" in one of the answers and then the following comments.