# Bluetooth on Ubuntu 18.04 and XPS13 completely gone (even after reboot)

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, xps

I have already had `bluetooth` problems, it disappeared after suspending and then I found a [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061437/bluetooth-on-xps13-9370-with-ubuntu-18-04-disappears) by updating to a newer kernel version. My mouse worked for several weeks... suddenly today out of NOTHING my bluetooth is completely gone! Even after reboot I can't get it back!

Does anybody has similar problems on `18.04` ? Maybe it has to do with some system updates from Canonical? Does anybody know what could help to get `bluetooth` back?

This is what the bluetooth menu shows me, everything is just greyed out:

[image]
PS: This is SO annoying! Is there a good place to report all these bugs to Canonical? Something like a Guthub issue tracker?

**EDIT:**

Here is the output of `uname -r; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`:

```
4.18.8-041808-generic
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2109:0100 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:58f4 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.032793] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    5.068829] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    6.368422] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[    9.312170] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp crc32 fd869beb
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `uname -r; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: @Jeremy31 thanks for the feedback, I have edited the question

Comment: Try removing the wifi card and put in back in.  The bluetooth chipset isn't being found at all

Comment: @Jeremy31 I have an XPS13, can't remove it! :-/

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C5LQE8z_rGM

Comment: Thx, I have the newest model 9370, but I will give it a try. But my WiFi works well, its only the bluetooth. I don't know if its one module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was:

`Shutting down`, waiting a few minutes and then `turning on` again worked for me.

No `restart`! Multiple restarts (about 10x) didn't help!

PS: If this still doesn't work, try to turn off the bluetooth-device inside bios, then restart and turn it on again.

Comment: That did the trick for me. It was due to an a firmware update from Dell.
When restarting, firmware upgrade is not applied. So you need to power off / power on.
But be sure to plug-in power soure, otherwise firmware upgrade process will not start !!!