# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS - wifi and bluetooth crashes

Tags: drivers, wireless, 18.04, bluetooth, dell

Recently upgraded my Dell XPS 13 from 16.04 to 18.04 and both the wifi and bluetooth consistently crashes where the settings page displays no wifi and bluetooth detected.

The only way to recover is to...

1. Restart into BIOS to unselect WLAN and Bluetooth
2. Restart into Ubuntu
3. Restart into BIOS to select WLAN and Bluetooth
4. Restart into Ubuntu
5. Back to normal

I find that wifi crashes at random, but 7 out of 10 times it will crash when wake from sleep, and bluetooth crashes every 2 days or so.  This didn't happen when I was on 16.04.

I am quite new to Linux, so I am a bit lost on how to figure this out.  Any help and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

The wireless card on board is QCA6174 802.11ac.

===============================================

UPDATE:

So I have figured out Bluetooth problem.  It was actually answered in [Dell XPS 13 (9370) Bluetooth issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024281/dell-xps-13-9370-bluetooth-issues).  Basically, replace the existing driver with an older Windows version.  The Bluetooth might still crash from time to time, but it will recover itself.

As for Wifi, it is somewhat solved as well.  It seems to be a timing issue.  What I've noticed is that after I wake my laptop from sleep, I need to wait a few seconds for the Wifi icon to appear at the task bar.  If I don't and log in too quickly, the Wifi and Bluetooth won't come back on.

And instead of restarting them in BIOS as mentioned before, I can just put my laptop to sleep, wake it up again and wait for the Wifi icon.

I feel like the Wifi problem can be solved w/ a script or some sort of configuration change.  Unfortunately, I haven't had any luck in figuring it out how or where.  I am a newbie in Linux, maybe I am not looking at the right place.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For wifi problem in ubuntu 18.04:

1. Open Terminal
   then enter the following commands one by one
2. git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
3. cd rtlwifi_new
4. git checkout origin/extended -b extended
5. sudo make install
6. sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de
7. sudo modprobe rtl8723de

Now the WiFi is ready to use.
But i still have the problem with the Bluetooth.
Any help with it would be appreciated.
Thank You.